# Android display text from a text file into my TextView in a non-stop loop

Tags: android, textview

I am working on an android app in which I have a text file with a list of text and duration of display in seconds.
The app displays the text listed in for the mentioned duration.
It keeps looping non-stop.
Now my question is: how can I retrieve the text in the text file and display it into my TextView?

Answer (score 0):

```
final StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
                    try {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                                file));
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            text.append(line);
                            text.append("\n");
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                    }
```